# Вопрос о generic-ах в Java -е

Tags: java, generics

Как получить доступ к методам классах наследниках. Например

```
public class Main <T extends Robot> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
 public static void call(T t){
  // Чтобы вот здесь видел метода sayB 
   t.
  }
}
public class Robot
{

}
public class Body extends Robot
{
    public void sayB(){
        System.out.println("sayb");
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавить метод `sayB` в `class Robot`

Comment: Вы передаёте в метод тип, о котором известно только то, что он  наследует `Robot`. Соответственно, вы можете вызывать только те его методы, которые имеет `Robot`. Можно явно привести `t` к типу `Body`, но это костыль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически вы можете создать функцию sayAny() в `Robot`

```
public class Robot
{
  public void sayAny(){

  }
}
```

А в классе `Body` переопределить метод `sayAny`, так чтобы он вызывал `sayB`

```
public class Body extends Robot
{
    @Override
    public void sayAny(){
       this.sayB();
    }

    public void sayB(){
        System.out.println("sayb");
    }
}
```

И тогда в функции `call` вы можете косвенно вызвать функцию `sayB` с помощью `sayAny`

```
public class Main <T extends Robot> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

    public static void call(T t){
      t.sayAny();
    }
}
```